# Meaning of "as a joke" in Harry Potter quote

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At last, a great crunching noise announced Hagrid’s return. Malfoy,
>   Neville, and Fang were with him. Hagrid was fuming. Malfoy,
>   it seemed, had sneaked up behind Neville and grabbed him **as a
>   joke**. Neville had panicked and sent up the sparks.

Someone who has read Harry Potter I , explain the bold phrase according to the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Malfoy thought that it would be funny to scare Neville. Put another way, he thought that scaring him would be a good [joke](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/joke). (See definition 1.1 on the *Oxford Dictionaries online* link provided.)
To pull off this "joke" Malfoy approached Neville quietly and from behind and and grabbed him.
That caused Neville to send up a signal of sparks.
Malfoy, of course, has a sense of "humour" that not everyone shares.